# Can a single 8" flex duct be split into a 5" flex and 7" flex?

Tags: hvac, ducts, central-air, heat-pump

Our house used to have a fur-down A/C unit that fed a series of rigid ducts made with duct board.  We'd like to replace a vent in our bathroom (5' x 11') with a 5" flex duct.  We'd like to replace a vent in our kitchen with a 7" flex duct.

Based on the research I've done, It seems we can take a single 8" flex duct off the output plenum and split it into a 5" flex and 7" flex.

Do all those sizes seem appropriate for the rooms?  Can I really split an 8" flex into a 5" flex and 7" flex?

I'm also wondering if 7" would be big enough for the kitchen so I'm considering going with a 8" flex.  So could I run a 10" flex and split it into a 5" flex and 8" flex?

Are there any issues with using a flex duct as a "trunk" line to the splitter?  Or would it be better to use a rigid duct to the splitter and then go with flex lines from there?

Answer (score 1):

The volume of a round duct can be generally estimated using its cross section. Pi * r^2
For an 8" it's 16Pi
7" is 12.25Pi
5" is 6.25 Pi.

18.5 > 16, so this is an oversized split.

However, using a 6" instead of a 7 gives you 9Pi.
9+6.25=15.25

So splitting an 8 into a 5+6 is a bit smaller, a 5+7 a bit bigger.
Given the choice I'd go 5+7 but if the rooms *require* 5+7 then it will be insufficient.

A 10" would be 25Pi, and that will happy split into 7+7 or 8+6.

Comment: This is great information.  Thank you.  Forgive me for asking, but whether the room requires 5+7 comes down to what?  System load balancing and CFMs and ACHs and FPMs and all the other intricacies in balancing a system?